# Learning Polymorphism java

Tags: java, polymorphism

still a learning student and I am kind of working on learning polymorphism here, and here is an activity given to me. I cannot understand how to use polymorphism. I have 4 classes here RunQuad as its main class, and the other three is where the polymorphism should've happen, and I do not know how to use it in the main class through polymorphism. Still not created the part of the code for the rectangle because I'm still working on the first one. There is still a continuation on this activity, but I think I'll try understanding the answers in this one and go solo in the rest.

The output that I wanted:

Press R for Rectangle or S for Square.

S

-has 4 equal sides

-has 4 right angles

-is quadrilateral

```
import java.util.*;    

class Quadrilateral 
    {
    public void showDescription()
    {
        System.out.println("- quadrilateral");
    }
}

class Rectangle extends Quadrilateral
{
    Rectangle()
    {
        super();
    }
    
    public void showDescription()
    {
        System.out.println("- has 4 right angles");
    }
}

class Square extends Rectangle
{
    Square()
    {
        super();
    }
    
    public void showDescription()
    {
        System.out.println("- has 4 equal sides");
    }
}



public class RunQuad
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char sr;
        
        System.out.println("Press R for Rectangle or S for Square. ");
        sr = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        
        if(Character.toUpperCase(sr) == 'S')
        {
            //polymorph here?
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare an local variable of type `Quadrilateral`, and assign a new `Rectangle` or `Square` object to that variable, then you can call the `showDescription()` method.

Because of polymorphism, that method call will call the version of the method that is on the actual object, regardless of the declared type of the local variable.

*FYI:* If you want the call to also print the messages from the superclass(es), then the methods needs to be changed to also call the `super` method.

Since this is obviously an exercise for you to complete, I'm not going to give you the actual code, but hopefully this description helps.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I should go with this:

Quadrilateral quad = new Quadrilateral();

Quadrilateral squ = new Square();

Quadrilateral rect = new Rectangle();

not this:

Quadrilateral quad = new Quadrilateral();

Square squ = new Square();

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();

Comment: @RichardJohnson Of the 6, you should #2 and #3, but assign to same local variable, depending on user input. That way you only need to write one call to `showDescription()`, showcasing how polymorphism works.

Comment: Oops, wait.. I should just call either the square or rectangle and utilize the super method.. is that correct?

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really enough problem here to illustrate polymorphism, or at least to illustrate its usefulness.

If you had an array of `Quadrilateral` objects, you could instantiate a number of `Square`s and `Rectangle`s and put them (actually references to them) into the array. Then you could call your `showDescription()` method on any of them without caring which class they were.

Likewise, you could have an array of objects of, say, `Shape`, that represented different shapes on a screen or page, and each of them would have a `draw()` method; you could call that on every member of the array to (re)draw all the shapes on the page, and the caller would not have to know what the individual shapes were.

This is the point of having subclasses; the base class represents an object which has different specific behavior but some same general behavior as other objects, and that COMES FROM the fact that the subclasses are special cases of the superclasses.

In your program, you could declare a variable of type `Quadrilateral`; when the user chooses which one, you could store either an instance of `Rectangle` or an instance of `Square` in that variable, and could then call `showDescription()` on that variable because it does not matter which instance is there. But it's a very weak illustration of polymorphism.